# Which algorithm to use to get longest string matching in two big arrays?

Tags: algorithm

The problem is easy to explain: we have two big arrays (32 bit integer values) and we have to find all common sequences above a given number of consecutive position (n).

For instance, if n=3 and arrays to compare are:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0, 4, 6]
b = [2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 0]
```

The algoritmh should return, two arrays:

```
r0 = [5, 7, 3, 2]
r1 = [3, 2, 7, 4, 6]
```

(or better, its relative positions to first array and the number of consecutive bytes matched).

I believe a good point to start is the [Longest Common Substring Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), but perhaps anybody knows an algorithm that fits better or exactly with my problem.

Comment: I belive this belongs on [Math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is an open research problem often studied in the context of matching/aligning DNA sequences. You might have some better luck researching how folks are doing this with DNA, or even find some available libraries.

Comment: @Mark: How is this an open research problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the algorithm for finding LCS using suffix tree is a perfect fit. You build the suffix tree the same way, but in the final phase, you're not looking for the deepest node that has descendants for both strings. You're looking for all nodes with the depth of more than `n` that have descendants for both strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the algorithms on the wikipedia page you reference do almost exactly what you want. You just need to modify them to keep all answers over a certain size rather than only keeping the longest answer. For instance, the dynamic programming solution on that page could be modified as follows:

```
function LCSubstr(S[1..m], T[1..n], min_size)
    L := array(1..m, 1..n)
    ret := {}
    for i := 1..m
        for j := 1..n
            if S[i] = T[j]
                if i = 1 or j = 1
                    L[i,j] := 1
                else
                    L[i,j] := L[i-1,j-1] + 1
                if L[i,j] >= min_size
                    ret := ret ∪ {S[i-z+1..z]}
    return
```

As written this will include prefixes as well as longest matches. Those could be filtered out by tracking what string was found into L and removing a prefix from the return set when we discover that it has an extension.

Comment: +1, but I'd emphasise that you really do want the O(m+n) generalised suffix tree solution instead of the O(mn) DP solution if m and n are large, as the OP claims they are.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly and n is the minimal size of a sequence, 
then I'de use a variation on Boyer-Moor's search algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore)

Comment: But BM algorithm is not for string search? My problem is to find all substrings between two big strings

Comment: a string is inherently a sequence of digits from one domain so it basically doesnt matter.
You could simply set the substring to search as every array_size/n sequence possible (from position i to i+n, from i+1 to i+1+n...) and do BM.
(If a larger identical sequence exist, you'll find the initial n-sized sequence and could simple continue testing for a larger suffix)

Comment: I know, so what you could do is use it by search for every substring (with size n) from the first array in the second array

Comment: Use of a suffix tree or trie might be better in this case as producing every substring from a base string is an n^2 operation. Couple that with a best case BM and you're looking at mn^2 at best.